# Warning: fopen() [function.fopen]: Filename cannot be empty in

Tags: php, caching, fopen

Im using this tutorial http://papermashup.com/caching-dynamic-php-pages-easily/ for caching a page

```
<?php {
$cachefile = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'cache.html';
$cachetime = 4 * 60;
// Serve from the cache if it is younger than $cachetime
if (file_exists($cachefile) && time() - $cachetime < filemtime($cachefile)) {
    include($cachefile);
} else {
ob_start(); // Start the output buffer
 ?>

/* Heres where you put your page content */


<?php 
// Cache the contents to a file
$cached = fopen($cacheFile, 'w');
fwrite($cached, ob_get_contents());
fclose($cached);
ob_end_flush(); // Send the output to the browser
}
?>
```

but i get the following errors

```
Warning: fopen() [function.fopen]: Filename cannot be empty in

Warning: fwrite(): supplied argument is not a valid stream resource in

Warning: fclose(): supplied argument is not a valid stream resource in
```

The path to the file is right. And if i edit the file my self is included but again i get the errors

Comment: What does `var_dump()`ing the relevant variable tell you?

Comment: What is the path to the file?  Is it relative or absolute?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You have a problem with the casing of your variable name. PHP variable names are case sensitive. Change `cacheFile` to `cachefile` (with the small **F** instead).

Change this:

```
$cached = fopen($cacheFile, 'w');
```

To this:

```
$cached = fopen($cachefile, 'w');
```

Answer (score 4):

You got a spelling error: `$cachefile` != `$cacheFile` PHP identifiers are case sensitive. So decide for one version and correct the other occurences.

Corrected Code:

```
$cached = fopen($cachefile, 'w');
```

Answer (score 3):

The first time you reference `$cachefile`. The second time you reference `$cacheFile`. Fix the casing in one place or the other and you should be good.

Answer (score 0):

For me it's because of I have insufficient permission on the file, so I resolved it with `chmod`